# German word starting with 'Knall' meaning a spontaneous, unscheduled abrupt meeting

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

I saw someone asking this question.
Is there a German word meaning 'a spontaneous, unscheduled, unexpected, abrupt meeting' starting with 'Knall~' ?

Comment: Maybe you are thinking of "Zusammenknall" depending on what you mean with meeting. But even then Knall is at the end.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a word ***Knalleffekt*** used for a spontaneous, unexpected, sudden event (of any kind). But I am not aware of a word starting with *Knall* (which means *bang*) especially for a meeting.

You could of course create one, e.g. ***Knalltreffen***, but then you are in the realm of poetry, not everyday or business communication. (And pay attention to what Takkat adds regarding *Knalltreffen* in his separate answer!)

The *Duden Universalwörterbuch* (some current edition) lists for *Knall*:

- Knallbonbon
- Knallcharge
- Knalleffekt
- Knallerbse
- Knallerei
- Knallfrosch
- Knallgas
- Knallkopf
- Knallkörper
- Knalltüte

as well as the adjectives

- knallblau
- knallgelb
- knallgrün
- knallrot
- knallbunt
- knalleng
- knallheiß
- knallig
- knallvoll

None of them means "sudden meeting".

However, you can think of various words starting with ***Blitz*** (lightning). The following terms are hardly to be found in contemporaneous dictionaries, but *Blitz* is more productive than *Knall*, meaning that you can create new words without being looked at with puzzlement. So ***Blitzkonferenz*** would pass almost unrecognized as a neologism, also ***Blitz-Meeting***, ***Blitzbesprechung***, ***Blitzgespräch***, ***Blitztreffen***. I could imagine finding these words used in some (informal) business communication, e.g. in e-mails to schedule a quick meeting.

Comment: +1 for thinking of _Blitz_!

Comment: What?  No [*knallhart*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475317/)? That's the only know I knew!

Comment: @gerrit  Yes, you are right. Interesting. *Knallhart* definitely should be in the listing.

Comment: @Janka  Good idea. More precisely, however, a *Knall-auf-Fall-Treffen* would be a meeting that takes place immediately after an important trigger event, and the peculiar thing is that it takes place immediately, not, say, after some time. So, a *Knall-auf-Fall-Treffen* is something more specific than a (supposed) *Knalltreffen* that takes place suddenly but without explicit relation to a trigger event.

Answer (score 2):

*This needs to be mentioned:*

---

The only context I heard of *Knalltreffen*  is from dingy contact queries on certain red light district announcements.

Examples (links for obvious reasons not included but with Google you will find them easily if the source is not banned on your machine):

> - Suche einen aufgeschlossenen Charmeur für geile Knalltreffen.
> - Suche für unregelmäßige Knalltreffen gesunde, schlanke Herren.

In these cases *Knalltreffen* is used for the original intention behind such contacts where *[knallen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/knallen)* is used in its vulgar meaning for having sexual intercourse. If any of these meetings follow they may be spontaneous but not really unscheduled, or unexpected. I can not exclude that the meaning may be regionally different, but where I live it is definitely not a word people know.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that the word is indeed in use.

Comment: Interesting indeed. I would add, that the verb _knallen_ in its meaning of _to have sexual intercourse_ is rather obscene in german, just as its literal _to bang_ in english.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach - Good addition! It is all rather offensive language, so no wonder we know nothing about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a substantive, associating sudden occurence with *Knall*. I also find this plausible, since *Knall* more often than not also indicates the **termination** of something (like a bursting balloon).

So *Blitz-* as in *Blitzkrieg* is the more likely choice (and its also used in English if I consider *flash mob*).

There is also the term *ad hoc* leaned from Latin ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/ad%20hoc) gives the meaning *aus dem Augenblick heraus*, probably translated to *instantaneous*) if just the improvised nature shall be pointed out, so the usual scheduling activities with notification weeks before are bypassed.